# Set view content from string in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I'm trying to return a view without view file *(.cshtml)*, Actually, I want to hard code view content as it seems there is no way to embed a view in asp.net core v2.1.

I wonder is there any way to return something like this:

`return View("@model ViewModel.ServiceView@{ Domain.Service item = Model.Item;}... ")`

Comment: What's the point of putting the "View" code in the "Controller" code? You're breaking the purpose of the pattern. I strongly suggest you not to do that. Even that means you need to create a view with only few lines of code. But you never know what you gonna add more in future.

Comment: @Alex-TinLe Thanks for your answer, I agree with you and you are right, but I have to include all my views into NuGet package. I have tried all suggested ways on the internet but none of them worked :(

Comment: @Alex-TinLe did you tried creating a nuget from [razor class library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/ui-class?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio)?

Comment: ASP.NET Core 2.1 does support view compilation.